# Python: Print Result Only

Tags: python

```
import os
def find_method(name):
        i = 0
        found_dic = { "$_GET":[], "$_POST":[], "include":[], "require":[], "mysql_query":[], "SELECT":[], "system":[], "exec":[], "passthru":[], "readfile":[], "fopen":[], "eval":[] }

        for x in file(name, "r"):
                i += 1
                for key in found_dic:
                        if x.strip().find(key) != -1:
                                found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + x.strip())

        print "="*20, name, "="*20
        for key in found_dic:
                if found_dic[key]:
                        print " ", "-"*10, key, "-"*10
                        for r in found_dic[key]:
                               print "  ",r

def search(dirname):
        flist = os.listdir(dirname)
        for f in flist:
                next = os.path.join(dirname, f)
                if os.path.isdir(next):
                        search(next)
                else:
                        doFileWork(next)

def doFileWork(filename):
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
        #if ext == '.html': print filename
        if ext == '.php':
               # print "target:" + filename
                find_method(filename)
```

1. how can I print only results. its prints all name of file eventhough file doesn't have any result in it. I want to make print file name if its has any result in it
2. this is about searching word, but it shows every word include like (seaching for include) then it also finds word in sentence and prints all sentence I want to find only word "include" not included in sentence. it's really hard to explain.. I hope to understand.. srry

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  Examples would probably go a long way.  Renaming `x`, `i`, `r`, and possibly `key` and `found_dic` to something a bit more readable would probably go a long way toward alleviating confusion for mere mortals like myself, as well.

Comment: you didn't give us your full program. `found_dic` is never defined, and neither is `i`.

Comment: also, please fix your indentation - there should be 4 spaces per indent, no mixing spaces and tabs

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you asked for:

```
for i, line in enumerate(file(name, "r")):
    found = False
    for key in found_dic:
        if key in line.strip():
            found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + key)
            found = True

    if found:
        print "="*20, name, "="*20
        for key in found_dic:
            if found_dic[key]:
                print " ", "-"*10, key, "-"*10
                for r in found_dic[key]:
                    print "  ",r
```

You have to check if you found something if you only want to print the name when you actually found something. Also, you only concatenate key in line 5, because key is what you search. And you only want to add what you search.

Further changes:
I used the enumerate function in line i, its far easier and more readable than incrementing you own i.

I also changed the condition in line 10. Using the in keyword here is the more simple and readable way...

Comment: thx for helping me but there some prob with it like this is example of my tool ==== /var/www/html/zboard/zboard.php ==================== ---------- exec ---------- LINE:288:$a_setup="<a onfocus=blur() href='admin_setup.php?exec=view_board&no=$setup[no]&group_no=$setup[group_no]&exec2=modify' target=_blank>"; else $a_setup="<Zeroboard ";
 <- i need this to show

Comment: could you please post example input and example output in your question? And best so that it is well formatted. I am not sure what exactly it is you need to show

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a problem with the indentation of the first print command, you are printing 'name', but it is outside of the for loop.

Try populating your dictionary, and then printing the dictionary, along the lines of:

```
with open(your_file) as f:
    found_dic = {}
    key = 'your_key'

    # populate the dictionary
    found_dic[key] = [i for i in f if key in i and i not in found_dic]
```

With this as a starting point, hopefully you can format the result to the dictionary as you need it. Only lines that include the 'key' will be in the found_dic, so you should be able to print these out in any format you like.

Hope this helps